# Is it possible to compile from Windows to Linux with gcc/g++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, g++, cross-compiling

Apologies for the beginner question.

In short I'm trying to compile a very simple C++ program for Linux from Windows 10. A few  answers say "install cygwin" but I'm not sure it's the optimal solution. Would it be simpler to just install Linux and build for Linux from Linux and for Windows from Windows, or do cross-compilers already exist that could take care of the work for me?

Thank you

Edit: maybe my question wasn't clear. Essentially, I'm using VSCode on Windows. I have C++ code that I'd like to compile for Linux from Windows. I installed MinGW and it lets me compile Windows executables without issue. However I have no idea on how to compile executables for Linux.

Comment: Windows 10 has WSL2. You can run linux inside windows. No need to cross-compile. I can highly recommend it. Pretty much everything you need works straight out of the box, like vs code integration, network/port mappings, you can access both filesystems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several choices:

1. **WSL**.
   WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) its linux termanal in windows, so you can compile linux code in windows. This solution is the simpliest and I would recommend to use it.
2. **Visual studio**.
   Visual studio has a package that allows you to compile programs for Linux. More details [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Are you referring to this?
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Comment: @catharsis Since you are developing in VSCode -- yes

Answer (score 1):

The Linux and Windows libraries have some implementation differences. And also  have different executables. Windows project may not work on Linux. But you can use the **Visual Studio IDE** with the Linux Developer Extension. Or can use **WSL (Linux terminal for Windows)** with Visual Studio Code (just install correct extension).

Answer (score 0):

Compiling a very simple C++ program for Linux from Windows 10 can be done on a vanilla Windows 10 system by installing an Arm-provided, mingw32, [toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads):

Aarch32/Arm 32 bit:
[gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.3-2021.07/binrel/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz)

Aarch64/Arm 64 bit:
[gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-mingw-w64-i686-aarch64-none-linux-gnu](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/10.3-2021.07/binrel/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-mingw-w64-i686-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz)

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand the question. But when I start linux and try to make a C++ program. I started by trying to install the compiler through the terminal, then made a simple C++ program, and it worked. To begin with I visited this site :

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-g-the-c-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Hopefully can help

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. In short, I want to compile a C++ program I wrote on VSCode on Windows. I built a tiny console app (literally just a single cout followed by a cin) and tried building it using g++. It makes an executable that works just fine on Windows but somehow I was not able to run the same thing Linux. I assume this is probably because I'm not using a proper cross-compiler?

Comment: @catharsis: Correct. Windows executables expect the Windows OS, Linux executables expect Linux. (Approximately, Android is a special sort of Linux).